# SSIS Execute SQL Task Error using Parameters

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

SSIS 2012....I want to post a success message to a SQL table in the same DB where I'm working. I created a variable called "InputRowCount" as Int32, and set it in the RowCount transform. Then, in a SQL Task, I set it as an input parameter, incidentally giving it a name. My DB connection is OLEDB, so the book says I just use a "?" to reference the lone Parameter (I expect to insert more parameters later....) It gets a "Parameter name is unrecognized" error. Here's the SQL Statement:

[Edit...now I get that the parameter type cannot be deduced...]

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "INSERT INTO dbo.tblpendingmessages 
>         ([Recipi..." failed with the following error: "The parameter type for '@P1' cannot be uniquely deduced; two possibilities are 'float' and 'datetimeoffset(7)'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

[image]

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.tblpendingmessages 
      ([Recipient]
      ,[MessageSubject]
      ,[MessageBody]
      ,[MessageGenerated]
      ,[MessageUser]
      ,[MessageFormat])
      VALUES    
    (N'CPAS_Administrator@xxxxxx.COM'           -- Recipient
    ,N'All Projects Import'             -- Subject Line
    ,N'ALL Projects Import has replaced ' + FORMAT(?,'N','en-us') + N' rows of the AllProjects Table in CPAS.'  -- MessageBody
    ,GETDATE()                  -- MessageGenerated
    ,N'SSIS'
    ,N'TEXT')
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: What does your Parameter tab look like?

Comment: A screen shot of the parameter tab would be super helpful.

Comment: If your ParameterName is `NewParameterName`, then you will need to replace that with 0

Comment: Can it be the FORMAT() function?

Comment: I changed the SQL by adding a {"DECLARE @RowCount INT"  "SET @RowCount=?"} in front of the prior SQL, then changed the parameter in the FORMAT() function to {@RowCount} instead of ?. Worked.  When all else fails, bludgeon it to death....lol Thanks guys